# Convert Gregorian date to solar in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, farsi

I have included a code snippet in the `functions.php` file that converts the Gregorian date to solar.

I use the following `shortcode` to display the publication date of my posts, which correctly converts from Gregorian to Solar:

```
<?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?>
```

I also use the following `shortcode` to display my posts updates:

```
<?php the_modified_time('Y/m/d'); ?>
```

The date conversion code for this `shortcode` doesn't work and still shows me Gregorian date.

Is it possible to edit this code so that the `shortcode` also supports updating the date and converts it to solar date?

The code I put in the `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('the_time', 'change_date_format');

function change_date_format(){
    //change date language here
    $date = get_the_time('Y/m/d');
    $date = explode('/', $date);
    $farsi_date = g2p($date[0],$date[1],$date[2]);
    return $farsi_date[0].'/'.$farsi_date[1].'/'.$farsi_date[2];
}

function g2p($g_y, $g_m, $g_d)
{
    $g_days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    $j_days_in_month = array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29);

    $gy = $g_y-1600;
    $gm = $g_m-1;
    $gd = $g_d-1;

    $g_day_no = 365*$gy+floor(($gy+3)/4)-floor(($gy+99)/100)+floor(($gy+399)/400);

    for ($i=0; $i < $gm; ++$i){
        $g_day_no += $g_days_in_month[$i];
    }

    if ($gm>1 && (($gy%4==0 && $gy%100!=0) || ($gy%400==0))){
        /* leap and after Feb */
        ++$g_day_no;
    }

    $g_day_no += $gd;
    $j_day_no = $g_day_no-79;
    $j_np = floor($j_day_no/12053);
    $j_day_no %= 12053;
    $jy = 979+33*$j_np+4*floor($j_day_no/1461);
    $j_day_no %= 1461;

    if ($j_day_no >= 366) {
        $jy += floor(($j_day_no-1)/365);
        $j_day_no = ($j_day_no-1)%365;
    }
    $j_all_days = $j_day_no+1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 11 && $j_day_no >= $j_days_in_month[$i]; ++$i) {
        $j_day_no -= $j_days_in_month[$i];
    }

    $jm = $i+1;
    $jd = $j_day_no+1;

    return array($jy, $jm, $jd, $j_all_days);
}
```

Comment: I wasn't clear what you meant by a 'solar date' so I googled it. I got this from Wikipedia: _The Gregorian calendar, widely accepted as a standard in the world, is an example of a solar calendar._. What, exactly, are you trying to do here?

Comment: Hi. What I mean by solar calendar is the glorified calendar. For example, if today's date is **2023-05-23** in the Gregorian calendar, it will be **1402-04-04** in the solar or Jalali calendar. This code works perfectly for the **post publish shortcode**. But for the **post update shortcode**, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I have no idea what a 'glorified calendar' is, and you clearly have some understanding of 'solar calendar' that differs from the mainstream. As far as I can tell, the Jalali calendar is used only in Iran and Afghanistan, so this is clearly not a mainstream requirement. There's nothing wrong with that, but you should assume that many contributors here are not familiar with your interpretation of these terms, and word your question accordingly.

Comment: I have designed my template for Iran and I want the Gregorian date to be converted to solar date. I know that it is not possible to change all the WordPress date to another date, but it is possible to change the publication and update date of the posts to any other date.

Comment: My code works correctly. Only the post update part is not working. If you look at the code above, I have variable `$date = get_the_time('Y/m/d');` and after obtaining the Gregorian date, I changed it to Shamsi. Now I want to do the same thing to update, but I keep getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook another [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_modified_time/) with the same filter function you already use.

```
add_filter('the_modified_time', 'change_date_format');
```

Comment: Thank you for your very simple and short solution.

Comment: What filter should I use if I want to convert the dates that I use in the **WordPress admin** area to solar in the same way?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question completely. Try this hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_date_column_time/